# Is it possible to launch a dialog directly from a widget through AppIntent? (IOS 17)

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit, sirishortcuts, appintents

I'm currently following a tutorial to develop an iOS interactive widget. Basically, in my widget, I want to have a button that users can tap on to record a number. Ideally, I would like it to prompt the dialog with the number input field. In my research, I came across something called `requestValueDialog` that I can include in my parameters defined in the `AppIntent` class, so I thought this is how it's done.

```
struct MinimalIntent:AppIntent{
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Number Recorder"
  
  @Parameter(title:"Number", requestValueDialog: IntentDialog("Enter number")) // HERE
  var value: Int
  
  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    // do sth
    return .result()
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, while it works fine when I launch the app intent from shortcuts, it doesn't seem to work with my widget.

So, is there an actual way to do this that I don't know, or are we just not supposed to do it this way?